# Permutation of given set of numbers

Tags: permutation

I have spent a considerable amount of time in trying to find an algorithms which solves this problem.Most of the sites display the use of a recursive function to solve this problem.I am still relatively new to programming and not really able to understand the logic involved in the problems.It would totally be nice if someone tool time to completely elaborate and explain it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should give some more details on your particular problem. For example, which programming language you are using and some example input and the expected output for that input. Also, [check if a similar question has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=permutations), as this is a quite common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this post

[Understanding Recursion to generate permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537791/understanding-recursion-to-generate-permutations)

hopefully it will helpful ...